# Protractor - element.all().count() is waiting long where there is no such an elements

Tags: webdriver, protractor

I've got problem with some of my protractor tests.
In short word, i need to check some numer of elements on my page with number from previous filter. 
When filter is clicked there should be displayed only A alements, B elements number should be 0.

I realized that protactor is waiting for long time when

```
  it('displays only wireless rows', function () {
  clientsPage.clientWiredFilterFalse.click();

  clientsPage.getWirelessTableRows().count().then(function (numwireless) {
    expect(numwireless).toEqual(wirelessCount);// in a second
  });
  clientsPage.getWiredTableRows().count().then(function (numwired) {
    expect(numwired).toEqual(0);// 20-30 seconds

  });
});
```

On this page I've got 0 elements that i get from getWiredTableRows and some from getWirelessTableRows()

This first expect is executing instantly,
the second one is waiting for many second until it finally realizes that there is no such a element on the page .

Why protractor is waiting for some elements for appearing ? It only happens for me when there is 0 elements returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have experience with Selenium WebDriver, but most like Protractor has an **implicit wait** going on, which means it tries keep finding elements for a certain amount of time.

You'll probably need to turn this off (to 0), in order for the method to immediately return a value (similar issue for Selenium's `FindElements` method).

**This could be of interest to you**:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299567/where-to-put-implicitlywait-in-protractor